# Can't run android app on real device

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I'm on a Windows 7 device (Archos 101 Internet tab/Prestigio 7100c).  It's connected with PC via USB cable. USB debugging is enabled from device settings.

```
Device manager -> PMP7100c -> right click -> Update Driver Software 
-> Search Automatically For Updated Driver Software
-> Driver Software For Your Device Is Up To Date.
```

Then I open Eclipse

```
Run -> Run Configurations and select active devices as target -> apply
-> Run -> "No active compatible AVD's or devices found.
Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD."
```

Is "adb" driver different from Device Menager's "driver software for your device"?I assumed that it is different and downloaded adb driver from Archos site and I got some .zip file.How to configure it?

Comment: In Command Prompt, run `adb devices`. Is your device listed (and not offline)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- look for the USB driver for your device
- install it
- restart your command prompt

Answer (score 0):

To install the Android USB driver on Windows 7 for the first time:

Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select Manage.
Select Devices in the left pane.
Locate and expand Other device in the right pane.
Right-click the device name (such as Nexus S) and select Update Driver Software. This will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
Select Browse my computer for driver software and click Next.
Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)
Click Next to install the driver.
Or, to upgrade an existing Android USB driver on Windows 7 with the new driver:

Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select Manage.
Select Device Manager in the left pane of the Computer Management window.
Locate and expand Android Phone in the right pane.
Right-click Android Composite ADB Interface and select Update Driver. This will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
Select Install from a list or specific location and click Next.
Select Search for the best driver in these locations; un-check Search removable media; and check Include this location in the search.
Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)
Click Next to upgrade the driver.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a mac and are pretty sure you should already have the drivers for the device then make sure to click the check mark next to 'USB debugging' inside the 'Developer Options' in settings. I can't tell you how dumb I felt when I unlocked the developer options by pressing the build number seven times then saw the developer options were unlocked and assumed usb debugging would automatically be selected only to find out 30 min later that I had to touch the little box. Yeah... don't do dumb kids!

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change the active *USB computer connection* setting. I had the same problem while running a Beanstalk custom rom based on Android 4.3. It was solved by switching from the default *Media device (MTP)* to *Mass storage*. The device was then automatically recognized by eclipse.